# ¿Puede una tabla tener relación consigo misma?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Ocupo crear una tabla con MySQL que se llame `personal` y que tenga los siguientes campos:

```
 ---------------------------
|         personal         |
 ---------------------------
| id_personal    | int(11) |
| nombre         | varchar |
| puesto         | varchar |
| area_asignada  | varchar |
| jefe           |         |
| subdireccion   | int(11) |
----------------------------
```

El problema es que en el campo `jefe` debe de ir algun registro que exista en la misma tabla `personal` ya que un personal tambien puede ser jefe. Les agradeceria mucho que me ayudaran con la creacion de la tabla y la consulta para que no muestre la clave del jefe sino su nombre.

Answer (score 12):

Lo que puedes hacer, es definir una clave foránea para el campo `jefe` (le voy a cambiar el nombre a `id_jefe` para que quede más claro para qué sirve) que hace referencia a la misma tabla `personal`.

Ejemplo:

```
create table personal (
    id_personal int(11) not null primary key,
    nombre varchar(50),
    puesto varchar(50),
    area_asignada varchar(50),
    id_jefe int(11),
    subdireccion int(11),
    constraint jefe_fk foreign key (id_jefe) references personal (id_personal)
);
```

Y luego, si deseas hacer una consulta de los registros en la tabla que a la vez te devuelve el nombre del jefe (si lo hay), puedes hacerlo usando un `left join` con la misma tabla `personal`.

Ejemplo:

```
select emp.nombre,
       jefe.nombre as nombre_del_jefe
  from personal emp       -- emp: empleado
  left join personal jefe
    on jefe.id_personal = emp.id_jefe;
```

Aquí te dejo un enlace para que puedas probar un ejemplo en vivo: [**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/IFSG87193).

Comment: Para algo sencillo y quizá para aprender, ¿no sería un poco más fácil el uso de un simple _id_parent_?

Comment: @JoriusR: O sea, ¿te refieres a que sería mejor cambiar el nombre del campo `jefe` a `id_parent`?

Comment: No, me refiero a guardar simplemente el `id_personal` dentro del campo `jefe` y realizar una breve consulta de tipo `SELECT nombre FROM personal WHERE jefe = 2`

Comment: @JoriusR: Pero eso mismo es lo que estoy haciendo. Tal vez la confusión se deba al nombre del campo `jefe`. La voy a cambiar a `id_jefe` para que sea mas claro.

Comment: @sstan te sugiero usar otros alias mas específicos para las consultas; por ejemplo, `FROM personal AS [pers]` en lugar de `from personal e`.

Comment: @Mauricio: de acuerdo.

Answer (score 6):

Una estructura jerarquica en una tabla se puede implementar de varias formas:

- Una lista de adyacencia
- Conjuntos anidados
- Enumeración de ruta
- Tabla de cierre (también conocida como Relación de Adyacencia)

**EJEMPLO**

Se podría tener una tabla así:

```
 ---------------------------
|         personal         |
 ---------------------------
| id_personal    | int(11) |
| nombre         | varchar |
| puesto         | varchar |
| area_asignada  | varchar |
| parent_id      | int(11) |
| subdireccion   | int(11) |
----------------------------
```

Haciendo referencia solo al campo `id_personal` y `nombre` tendríamos una estructura así;

```
1 Juan
    2 Pedro
    3 José
       4 Carlos
```

Pasandolo a la tabla de la base de datos (solo haciendo referencia a los campos `id_personal`, `nombre` y `parent_id`):

```
 ----------------------------------------
| id_personal |   nombre   |  parent_id |
 ----------------------------------------
|       1     |    Juan    |      0     |
|       2     |    Pedro   |      1     |
|       3     |    José    |      1     |
|       4     |   Carlos   |      3     |
-----------------------------------------
```

Se puede ver que `parent_id` hace referencia al id del jefe de ese empleado, ese patrón se repite de manera indefinida hasta el nivel mas alto. Un ejemplo de consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM personal WHERE parent_id= 3;
```

Esta consulta devolvería todos los empleados que tienen por jefe (jefe inmediato) al empleado con id 3, que a su vez, podría tener o no un jefe. Para este caso, la consulta devuelve un resultado: **Carlos**.

Se recomienda que los items que estén en la cima de la jerarquía (Juan) que no tienen un elemento padre, se les ponga un **cero** como valor del `parent_id` a manera de bandera que indica el fin de la sucesión jerárquica.

Aquí está una referencia útil [Estructura de árbol en MySQL](http://desarrollandowebsdinamicas.blogspot.mx/2012/07/estructura-de-arbol-en-mysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sí quieres que una persona también pueda ser jefe, puedes agregar el campo indicando que `es_jefe` como un bolean, así ingresas `true` sí la persona es jefe y `false` sí no lo es.

```
 ---------------------------
|         personal         |
 ---------------------------
| id_personal    | int(11) |
| nombre         | varchar |
| puesto         | varchar |
| area_asignada  | varchar |
| es_jefe        | boolean |
| subdireccion   | int(11) |
----------------------------
```

Aquí estaría el Query para crear la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE personal (
    id_personal INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50),
    puesto VARCHAR(50),
    area_asignada VARCHAR(50),
    es_jefe BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    subdireccion INT(11),
);
```

Finalmente la consulta con la cual obtienes los nombres de los jefes sería:

```
SELECT nombre FROM personal WHERE es_jefe = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE personal
(
   idpersonal INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   nombre VARCHAR(100),
   puesto VARCHAR(100),
   areaasignada VARCHAR(100),
   jefe CHAR(1),
   subdireccion INT(11)
)
```

En el campo jefe que es un `CHAR(1)` pueden ir `S` o `N` si es jefe se pone `S` y si no lo es pone `N`

Consulta:

```
SELECT nombre FROM personal WHERE jefe='S'
```

El detalle que con esta implementación de Personal no se sabría quien es jefe de quien.

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus respuestas. Todas son buenas pero la que me sirvio fue la @sstan, **Gracias sstan!!**

Comment: @Foobar si te sirvio la respuesta de sstan marcala como respuesta.